# Opening a textpane in the same form on a Button click

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, runtime, jtextpane

I am trying to design a basic editor type of GUI in Java using Swing. I have a menu item named `New` clicking on which I want a blank text area to fill up the GUI. My code is as folows :

---

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class UI extends JFrame {
    private JMenuBar bar;
    private JMenu menu;
    private JMenuItem item;
    private JTextPane tp;

    public UI() {
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        bar = new JMenuBar();
        setJMenuBar(bar);

        menu = new JMenu("File");
        bar.add(menu);

        item = new JMenuItem("New");
        menu.add(item);
        item.addActionListener(new xyz());
    }

    public class xyz implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            JTextPane tp = new JTextPane();
            add(tp);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // do the rest of the stuffs
    }
}
```

---

However, even on clicking on the `New`, I do not get the textPane on the same frame. Can someone please explain.

Answer (score 1):

- use `JTextPane#setText("")` instead of to create a new `JTextPane`
- otherwise you have to notify `Container` with `(re)validate()` and `repaint()`

Comment: I tried this also : tp.setText(""); but it does not seem to work.

Comment: for better help sooner to post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)  about [JTextPane#setText()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html#setText%28java.lang.String%29)  doesn't work

Comment: @CSSS tp.setText("") does work. You should call it from your actionPerformed() method so that every time you click "New" the contents are cleared.

Answer (score 1):

The text-panes should probably be added to a `JTabbedPane` if this app. supports multiple documents.  If it is intended for 'single document', put the text pane onto the frame at start-up.